# OpenGL, GLFW библиотека, проблема с выводом позиции курсора мыши используя callback в Python 3.7!

Tags: opengl, glfw, python-3.7

Короче, в этом коде я использую **колбэк(калбек, кэлбек) функцию**, чтобы получить позиции курсора мыши:

```
import glfw


def main():
    # initialize glfw
    if not glfw.init():
        return

    window = glfw.create_window(800, 600, "GLFW Example File", None, None)

    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        return

    glfw.set_cursor_pos_callback(window, cursorchik) # set a callback function

    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
        glfw.poll_events()
        glfw.swap_buffers(window)

    glfw.terminate()


def cursorchik(window, x, y): # a callback funtion
    print(glfw.set_cursor_pos(window, x, y))
    return x, y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

выводит вместо чисел None:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Хочу получить числа вместо None, как это реализовать? или просто напишите рабочий код.**

Не говорите "*используй циклы с **glfw.get_cursor_pos(window)**!*" - да, так я получаю позиции курсора, но с циклом она выводит **БЕСКОНЕЧНО** те же позиции, когда курсор неподвижен, и ещё сама функция работает за пределами окна **window = glfw.create_window(800, 600, "GLFW Example File Presents", None, None)**,

***а с колбакими выводит только при движении и не за пределами окна GLFW, но не числа***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ПРОБЛЕМА РЕШЕНА!** Нужно было всего лишь убрать внутри **callback function** возвращаемый тип инструкции **return** и заменить его на **print(x, y)**, после убираем строку с **print(glfw.set_cursor_pos(window, x, y))** тогда всё и сработает!

```
import glfw


def main():
    # initialize glfw
    if not glfw.init():
        return

    window = glfw.create_window(800, 600, "GLFW Example File Presents", None, None)

    if not window:
        glfw.terminate()
        return

    glfw.set_cursor_pos_callback(window, cursorchik)

    glfw.make_context_current(window)

    while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
        glfw.poll_events()
        glfw.swap_buffers(window)

    glfw.terminate()


def cursorchik(window, x, y):
    print(x, y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Только непонятно, что делать с неиспользуемым аргументом **window** внутри **callback function**? но убрав её оттуда выдает ошибку!